# Unable to create GeoJSON layer

Tags: angular, leaflet, geojson, ngx-leaflet

I'm developing an app in angular that use leaflet map to show some layers and I'm trying to use GeoJSON, but I'm unable to create an L.geoJSON layer. I'm trying to add a point and every single resource I found tell me to create this structure:

```
import { geoJSON } from 'leaflet';

geoJSON({
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [lat,long]
});
```

but when I serve the app I get this error:

```
Argument of type '{ type: "Point"; coordinates: number[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GeoJsonObject'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'coordinates' does not exist in type 'GeoJsonObject'.
```

The only other property beyond `type` is `bbox?`.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't really understand what.

Using

```
"leaflet": "^1.3.1"
"@types/leaflet": "^1.2.5"
"@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^3.0.2"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Typed Definition for Leaflet specifies that the [`geoJSON` factory](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ddbf07cb69182b71500a31edd43937e42e1e5b51/types/leaflet/index.d.ts#L899) accepts a [GeoJSON Object](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bb7103dc31e040174216333350e3bd1ac99f547d/types/geojson/index.d.ts#L42-L63) ([spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3)) as 1st parameter.

The object you pass as 1st parameter is a [`Point`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bb7103dc31e040174216333350e3bd1ac99f547d/types/geojson/index.d.ts#L73-L80) type [Geometry Object](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bb7103dc31e040174216333350e3bd1ac99f547d/types/geojson/index.d.ts#L65-L71) ([spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1)), that extends the GeoJSON object. Therefore you should be good by simply **explicitly** declaring your object as a `geojson.Point`:

```ts
import { geoJSON } from 'leaflet';
import * as geojson from 'geojson';

geoJSON(<geojson.Point>{
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [lng, lat] // Note that in GeoJSON, order is [LONG, LAT]
});
```

Leaflet in JavaScript actually [accepts more types](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.3.1/src/layer/GeoJSON.js#L93-L108) as 1st parameter of [`L.geoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#geojson) factory:

- A GeoJSON Object ([`FeatureCollection`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.3), [`Feature`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2) or [Geometry object](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1))
- An array of GeoJSON Objects.

Comment: Thak you! That's not exactly intuitive..
So if I want do add a Feature, say a `LineString`, what I have to do is:

    `geoJSON(<geojson.Feature<geojson.LineString>>{
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [ 44.4992192, 11.3616455 ],
            [ 44.4992192, 13.3616455 ]
          ]
        }
      })`

Right?

Comment: Hum looks strange but hey, just give it a try. I would have put `<geojson.Feature>` first, then `<geojson.LineString>` for the `geometry` object. If you need help on that, it would be more convenient to open a new question, it is hard to show things in comments.

Comment: Yeah, noted :D
Last question: if I need to style my geoJSON how whould I do that? (If it's too long I'll open a new question)

Comment: Check Leaflet docs, it explains L.geoJSON factory options, including style. You should have plenty resources on that here on SO as well. If you still need help feel free to open a new question.